# How can I work with F# in Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2017

I updated **Visual Studio Enterprise to the last new version 15.3 Released** .

But when I write code in Visual F# , file Program.fs , **I can't use "Backspace"** .

I tried my best to can use it that I have to create a new file ***.fs** .

And what do you think about restarting VS , all errors're revival ?

Thank you to hear from me !

Comment: Visual Studio's support for F# is a bit flaky at the moment. At the minimum you should install the [F# Nightlies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/14/announcing-nightly-releases-for-the-visual-f-tools/), or even better start using [VSCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-vscode).

Comment: I think it installed during setting up Visual Emprise

Comment: You mean Visual Studio Enterprise, not that the edition matters. There are known bugs with F# support even in the latest update. This is a known *new*  bug. You should still use the nightly build

Comment: This bug for the most part appears in editor tabs that are automatically opened when your solution opens. Usually not just backspace but also arrow keys and maybe a few other keys are affected. A workaround is to close the files and reopen them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use nightly build of Visual F# Tool as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/14/announcing-nightly-releases-for-the-visual-f-tools/)

> 1. Open Tools -> Extensions and Updates.
> 2. Click "Change your Extensions and Updates settings" on the bottom-left corner.
> 3. Click "Add" under "Additional Extension Galleries".
> 4. Under "Name", enter anything you like. Under "URL", enter https://dotnet.myget.org/F/fsharp/vsix
> 5. Click "Apply".
> 6. Click "OK".
>
> It may take a few minutes for VS to refresh the feed, depending on your machine. Once that has happened, you can open Tools -> Extensions and Updates and notice that there is an update to the Visual F# tools!